# Pointer Events IE11/ Surface

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-11, surface, pointer-events

What is the best way to handle touch/pointer events on a surface tablet? I find its behavior quite confusing. 
I wrote a script that just set all the event handlers to figure out how the events are fired (setting native event handlers, using jQuery for the UI):

```
$.each([
    "touchstart","touchmove","touchend",
    "mousedown","mousemove","mouseup",
    "pointerdown","pointermove","pointerup",
    "MSPointerDown","MSPointerMove","MSPointerUp"
], function(i,eventname) {

    tester.addEventListener(this, function(e) {
        msg(eventname,e);
        if ($("#prevent").is(":checked")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if ($("#stop").is(":checked")) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        if ($("#stopimmediate").is(":checked")) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }

    }, false);
});
```

Using the mousepad or desktop IE11, everything is fine. All three events (mouse, pointer, MSPointer) are fired in the expected order: down, move, up.

But, when I use the tochscreen

- at first a pointermove fires, then pointer down. On the screen a rectangle appears around my finger.
- repeated move events are firing while *not* moving my finger
- firing no further events when I move my finger
- pointerend event when removing finger

What am I doing wrong? Calling preventDefault, stopPropagation or stopImmediatePropagation does not change this behavior. Setting the css *pointer-events: none;* disables all events.

[Complete script on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwukE)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [touch-action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj583807%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#control_default_touch) CSS property to prevent the browser's pan and zoom behaviours when the user drags accross the screen with a finger or stylus.

For example:

```
#prevent, #stop, #stopimmediate {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

Comment: Hum, this simply disables all events. Not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try my touch gesture abstraction library, [DeepTissue](http://DeepTissuejs.com). IE's touch model is extremely simply because the pointer events abstract all the input modalities into a common API. Chrome is making things complicated, but that is another story :).

You really do not want to hook into all the events. I get that it would be confusing. That is why I wrote Deeptissue. It keeps you from having to write all the plumbing code and it chooses the best option and hooks into that event set.

Comment: give me any feedback you have!